# why "NestedExceptionUtils" in spring source code is declared as an abstract class?

Tags: java, spring

I fount a util class in Spring named NestedExceptionUtils, and it is declared as an abstract class, why abstract? To prevent instances of it? But another class is not declared as an abstract class! Such as 'BeanDefinitionReaderUtils'. when should I do this?

Comment: Depends on which version you are looking at. The latest Spring 5.1 both are `abstract`. Utility classes are generally `abstract` and have a `private` no-args constructor to prevent sub-classing.

Answer (score 0):

`NestedExceptionUtils` contains a single `public static` method and has no derived classes (within Spring). This suggests that it's `abstract` to prevent instantiation.

Another and a slightly better way to create utility classes in Java is to declare a class `final` and define a `private` no-args constructor. This is better than `abstract` utility class because it also suppresses `extend`ing the utility class.

---

Spring wasn't written by a single person, this could explain why different utility classes are written in different ways.

Comment: 1.the two example class are written by the same person named 'Juergen Hoeller', there is no reason two classes have a different style. 2.even if they are written by different people,  don't spring team has a common style limited? I'm confused!

Comment: Well, the author would be the best person to ask for the reasoning, of course. But note that [`BeanDefinitionReaderUtils`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-beans/src/main/java/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/BeanDefinitionReaderUtils.java) has become `abstract` as well in Spring version 5.1.2.RELEASE.